# Image source not readable Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, image, laravel-5.8

When I want to add a picture to a post I have this error:

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Créer une annoce</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title">Titre</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="title" type="text" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}"  autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                                @error('title')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="descriptionpost">Description</label>

                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <textarea id="descriptionpost" type="text" class="form-control @error('descriptionpost') is-invalid @enderror" name="descriptionpost" value="{{ old('descriptionpost') }}"  autocomplete="descriptionpost" autofocus></textarea>

                                @error('descriptionpost')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <div class="custom-file">

                                <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" id="validatedCustomFile" >
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choisir une image</label>
                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="price">Prix</label>
s
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="price" type="text" class="form-control @error('price') is-invalid @enderror" name="price" value="{{ old('price') }}"  autocomplete="price" autofocus>

                                @error('price')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Créer
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Poststore;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    public function postsabonnés()
    {
    auth()->user()->following->pluck('user_id'); 
    $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->latest()->get();  
    return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(1000);

        return view('welcome',['posts'=> $posts]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
            'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'descriptionpost' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();


        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'descriptionpost' => $data['descriptionpost'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'image' => $imagePath
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', ['user' => auth()->user() ]);
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $words = $request->words;
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%$words%')->orWhere('descriptionpost', 'LIKE', '%$words%')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'posts' => $posts]);
    }
}
```

ProfileController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        $follows = (auth()->user()) ? auth()->user()->following->contains($user->profile->id) : false;

        return view('profile.show', compact('user', 'follows'));
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);
        return view('profile.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    public function update(User $user)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $user->profile);
        $data = request()->validate([
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'sometimes|image|max:3000'
        ]);

        if (request('image')) {
        $imagePath = request('image')->store('avatars', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(800, 800);
        $image->save();

auth()->user()->profile->update(array_merge($data,
    ['image' => $imagePath]
));
        } else {
            auth()->user()->profile->update($data);
        }

        auth()->user()->profile->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', ['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Modifier profile</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('profile.update', ['user' => $user]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PATCH')

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="description">Description</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <textarea id="description" type="text" class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror" name="description" autocomplete="description" autofocus>{{ old('description') ?? $user->profile->description }}</textarea>

                                @error('description')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <div class="custom-file">

                                <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" id="validatedCustomFile" >
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choisir une image</label>
                                @error('image')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Modifier profile
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I have this error when I want to add pictures in the post but when I try add picture in profile or want to edit a picture, the pictures load but its white.
I've read  that I need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` but when I add this it still did not work, what i can do to resolve this?

Comment: So what is the error? is it `Image source not readable Laravel 5.8`?

Comment: Can you confirm that the image is definitely saved in your file system?

Comment: yes its save in storage